# Postgresql: Is there any need to define single-column index on a column which is part of composite unique constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Let say I have Item table, with composite unique constraint on company_id and code columns.
As documented, postgresql creates index on this constraint automatically. But if some queries 
filter by company_id column but not code column, then to increase performance, should I define index on company_id column too?

Comment: Not sure about Postgresql, but in other DBs the columns are (to put it simplistically)combined to create a btree structure. The optimizer can use a composite index if a query uses the first column but probably won't if it uses only the second or third. In your case, it probably will use the composite index

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you defined your unique index (or constraint, which will automatically create a unique index with the affected columns, in that order).

> A multicolumn B-tree index **can be used** with query conditions that involve **any subset** of the index's columns, but the index is **most efficient** when there are constraints on the **leading (leftmost) columns**. The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of the index that is scanned ...

More in docs about [Multicolumn Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html)